# Adjust for multiple comparisons in multiple linear regression with upstream model selection step

Tags: multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons

Say I have two DV `y1` and `y2`, and three IV `x1`, `x2`, `x3`
I fit the models:

$y_{1} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + \beta_{3}x_{3} + \epsilon_{1}$
$y_{2} = \beta'_{0} + \beta'_{1}x_{1} + \beta'_{2}x_{2} + \beta'_{3}x_{3} + \epsilon_{2}$

and I'm interested in extracting the p-values for hypothesis testing. I would normally adjust my p-values family-wise, considering the coefficients grouped by the variable they are associated.
So for example, applying a Holm correction, $min(p_{\beta_{1}}, p_{\beta'_{1}})$ is multiplied by 2, $max(p_{\beta_{1}}, p_{\beta'_{1}})$ is multiplied by 1, and so on for the other coefficients.

But, say I am running some model selection by some criterion and I end up dropping one variable in one of the models, but not in the other, and end up fitting the models:

$y_{1} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + \beta_{3}x_{3} + \epsilon_{1}$
$y_{2} = \beta'_{0} + \beta'_{1}x_{1} + \beta'_{2}x_{2} + \epsilon_{2}$

What would be the best way to correct the p-values for multiple testing?

For the sake of exemplifying my concern, say I've found:
$p_{\beta_{3}} = 0.03$
$p_{\beta'_{3}} = 0.8$
If I were to reject the null hypothesis with confidence level $\alpha = 0.05$, the
$H_{0}: \beta_{3} = 0$
would not be rejected in the first set of models, but it would be rejected in the second set?